# if-else statement issue in awk

Tags: if-statement, unix, awk

I want to make a condition for processing my file but it doesn't work.
Here is my dataset:

```
CPOODT      #   DODS Date KPI               #DECIMAL    #    7.0        #1      #   Date
CPLWRB      #   DODS Code KPI               #CHAR       #    30         #2      #0
CPF1TE      #   DODS Valeur  KPI            #CHAR       #    30         #0      #0
CPF2TE      #   DODS Description KPI        #CHAR       #    50         #0      #0
CPEJZB      #   Date Created                #DECIMAL    #    7.0        #0      #   Date
CPAVZI      #   Time Created                #DECIMAL    #    6.0        #0      #   Heure
```

I try to run a condition so I can replace "char" with "string" and save the result in new file. Here is my code:

```
BEGIN {                                                                         
  FS="#"
}
{
if ($3=="CHAR") {$3=="string"} else {$3="decimal"}
printf($3   "(\"${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}\")"       "\t"   $1"= NULL(\"\")""\t""/*"     "\n")}
END {
printf("end")}
```

Unfortunately I get this as a result:

```
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")   CPOODT= NULL("")    /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")   CPLWRB= NULL("")    /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")   CPF1TE= NULL("")    /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")   CPF2TE= NULL("")    /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")   CPEJZB= NULL("")    /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")   CPAVZI= NULL("")    /*
```

This is the expected output:

```
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")   CPOODT= NULL("")    /*
string("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")    CPLWRB= NULL("")    /*
string("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")    CPF1TE= NULL("")    /*
string("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")    CPF2TE= NULL("")    /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")   CPEJZB= NULL("")    /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")   CPAVZI= NULL("")    /*
```

I don't want to use the `gsub` function and even if I replace the if-else with :  `#{ $3 = ($3 == "%CHAR%" ? -1 : $3) }`  I still get the same result.

My command line to run the function:

```sh
awk -f function1.awk input.txt>output.txt
```

---

EDIT by Ed Morton: here's the above code formatted by `gawk -o-` so its understandable:

```
BEGIN {
        FS = "#"
}

{
        if ($3 == "CHAR") {
                $3 == "string"
        } else {
                $3 = "decimal"
        }
        printf ($3 "(\"${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}\")" "\t" $1 "= NULL(\"\")" "\t" "/*" "\n")
}

END {
        printf ("end")
}
```

Comment: Going forward, please learn how to format your code to be readable (see the example I just added to the end of your question), it'll greatly help you and help others trying to help you. Now, for example, the `==` instead of `=` in `$3 == "string"` is extremely obvious.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are comparing against the literal string `"CHAR"` but the field contains trailing whitespace so it's never exactly equivalent.

Here's a significantly simplified version with this problem corrected.

```sh
awk -F '#' '{ print ($3 ~ /^CHAR/ ? "string" : "decimal") "(\"${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}\") \t" $1 "=NULL(\"\")\t/*" }
    END { print "end" }' input.txt
```

The expression `$3 ~ /^CHAR/` checks if the third field matches the regular expression `^CHAR` i.e. if the field's value *begins* with `CHAR`.

Answer (score 1):

With minimal changes to your code to just fix the FS definition and the `$3 == "string"` bug you get close:

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
        FS = "[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*"
}

{
        if ($3 == "CHAR") {
                $3 = "string"
        } else {
                $3 = "decimal"
        }
        printf ($3 "(\"${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}\")" "\t" $1 "= NULL(\"\")" "\t" "/*" "\n")
}

END {
        printf ("end")
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")       CPOODT= NULL("")        /*
string("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")        CPLWRB= NULL("")        /*
string("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")        CPF1TE= NULL("")        /*
string("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")        CPF2TE= NULL("")        /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")       CPEJZB= NULL("")        /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")       CPAVZI= NULL("")        /*
end$
```

and  the final version would be (assuming you really do want to print `end` at the end of the output):

```
$ cat tst.awk
BEGIN {
        FS = "[[:space:]]*#[[:space:]]*"
        OFS = "\t"
}

{
        $3 = ($3 == "CHAR" ? "string" : "decimal")
        print $3 "(\"${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}\")", $1 "= NULL(\"\")", "/*"
}

END {
        print "end"
}
```

```
$ awk -f tst.awk file
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")       CPOODT= NULL("")        /*
string("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")        CPLWRB= NULL("")        /*
string("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")        CPF1TE= NULL("")        /*
string("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")        CPF2TE= NULL("")        /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")       CPEJZB= NULL("")        /*
decimal("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")       CPAVZI= NULL("")        /*
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following, written and tested in shown samples in GNU `awk`. Mentioning string values in form of `awk` variables in program so that one could change them in case its needed in future in variable itself.

```
awk -v str1='= NULL("")    /*' -v str2='("${SEPARATEUR_ABINITIO}")   ' '
BEGIN{
  FS="#"
  OFS="\t"
}
{
  sub(/ +$/,"",$3)
  $3=($3=="CHAR"?"string":"decimal")
  print $3 str2,$1 str1
}
END{
  print "end"
}
'  Input_file
```